# SimpleSamlPhp with CustomIdP Implementation

Tags: php, single-sign-on, simplesamlphp

I'm just wondering if any you have a experience integrating SSO using SimpleSamlPhp and Custom IdP. We actually manage to make it work but we're just being skeptical regarding on the security and stability of the SSO using just SAML2.0 as our Service Provider and Identity Provider we're just allowed to use free SSO for now. So my questions is:

How's your experience in terms of security and stability of simplesamlphp?

Answer (score 0):

I use SimpleSAMLphp as an idP. If I need a php client library to implement SAML as a SP I use the OneLogin provided open source project as I have found it more simple / less bloated.

https://github.com/onelogin/php-saml